# Setting up GLFW on mac for scratchapixel

Tags: gcc, osx-mavericks, glfw

Following the guide over at http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-2-get-started/get-started/ and I got down to the part where you set up GLFW. Everything was going fine got CMake all installed properly and it went through the process just as shown on the images on the site. Everything installed fine to the /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib folders. So the next thing to do is test that it installed fine and every time I try to do anything with whats in the glfw folder, gives me this error:

```
fatal error: 'GLFW/glfw3.h' file not found
```

These are the commands I've tried to run it with:

```
gcc boing.c -o boing
gcc -lglfw boing.c -o boing
gcc -lglfw3 boing.c -o boing
gcc -I/usr/local/include boing.c -o boing (different error)
```

The last one almost worked and gave several different errors, which I think may have been caused by something else. That's kind of besides the point though. What am I doing wrong here? To my knowledge gcc is meant to look in the /usr/local/include folder by default for libraries.

Comment: Did you list the content of /usr/local/include? Is there a GLFW directory in there? You should get one. If not it's possible you actually successfully compiled GLFW but didn't install it. You also need to do something like make install in general. Scratchapixel is a great website btw.

Comment: The directory is in the proper place, and the contents are correct.

Comment: This is simply not possible. How do you declare the include file in boing.c? Like this #include "GLFW/glfw3.h"? When you do a ls -lrt /usr/local/include/GLFW/glfw3.h do you see the file? If that's the case, this is mystery. It should definitely not give you this message. Depending on the system you are compiling this program on, you may need more libs to your gcc cmd line. To be clear: gcc -I/usr/local/include boing.c -o boing this should work and if it doesn't it's because you need to declare more things.

Comment: By more things I mean more library. For example check on their page: http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-2-get-started/get-started/ they say: c++ -o imageviewer -L/path/to/glfw-3.0.1/lib/ -I/path/to/glfw-3.0.1/include imageviewer.cpp -lglfw3 -lX11 -lGL -lXrandr -lXi -lXxf86vm -lpthread -lrt -L/path/to/Cg/3.1/lib -I/path/to/Cg/3.1/include -lCgGL -lCg You obviously don't need the Cg/nvidia bits if you don't use it, but if you need GLFW you also need all the GL and X11 bits, etc.